# Tkinter, is it possible to def button(a,b,c,e)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a newbie so I'm possibly missing other way to do something like this. Im trying to:

```
def button(a,b,c,d,e,f):
    a=ttk.Button(b,text=c,command=d)
    a.grid(row=e, column=f)
```

so that i can creat buttons like this:

```
button(a,b,c,d,e,f)
```

Comment: You don't need to have `a` in arguments. But you should return it with `return a` at the end of your function

Comment: Also, there might be better parameter names than `b` through `f`...

Comment: Try it and see for yourself.

Comment: @phoenixo *you should return it*... Are you sure about this.  Return is not needed when adding widgets.

Comment: As pheonixo pointed out you do not need the `a` portion but the rest is fine. Try it and see what happens.

Comment: @Mike-SMT : If he wants to access this button once it is created, he needs to do something like `my_button = button(a,b,c,d,e,f)`. So in the function he must do `return a` at the end

Comment: @phoenixo that is one way. They can also get all the children of the container. In most cases buttons are not updated so that situation is unlikely. That said I am not even sure why the OP wants to add this extra step to building a button.

Comment: Of course I'll find better parameter names, b through f was for sake of brevity. It works very well omitting a and returning it at the end of definition,tho at this point i dont understand how each button is named.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I'm not sure either, I know it doesn't really make anythin g faster or simplier

Comment: @EsmailAlbertoGhassemi you may want to give a bigger example. How many buttons are you trying to set up? Why are you using a function instead of just use the defined parameters of the Button method? The solutions for most button creation can be a simple loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example of your button wrapper idea using sensible variable names.  The handle is a return value.  The switch button calls the tog function to switch the background color of the window, and the quit button destroys the window:

```
from tkinter import *

def button(container,
           txt_str,
           cmd_funcname,
           rowval,
           colval):
    handle=Button(container,text=txt_str,command=cmd_funcname)
    handle.grid(row=rowval, column=colval)
    return handle

def tog() :
    if window.cget( 'bg' ) == 'yellow' :
        window.configure( bg = 'gray' )
    else :
        window.configure( bg = 'yellow' )

window = Tk()
window.geometry('300x100')
window.title( 'Button Wrapper Example' )

btn_end = button(window,'Quit',window.destroy,0,1)              
btn_tog = button(window,'Switch',tog,1,1)

window.mainloop()
```